# Show hide animate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following show/hide function:

```
    // Show/hide filters on mobile //
$("#openMobileFilters").click(function(){   
    showOrHideFilter(true);
});
$(".closeFilters").click(function(){
    showOrHideFilter(false);         
}); 

function showOrHideFilter(show) {
    $("#results-container, .navbar-inverse" ).toggleClass( "hidden-xs", show );
    $("#filter-column").toggleClass("hidden-xs", !show); 
}
```

I wanted to add animation when the class is toggled. Something like:

```
.animate({ width: 'hide' });
```

I was unsure of how to combine this into the function?

Many thanks

Comment: please share your html code also. Share jsfiddle if you can.

Comment: what is the class `hidden-xs` definition... does it simple set the display

Comment: is `hide` a valid value for the `width`? or is it a jQuery animate feature?

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/eLftj5nn/1/

Comment: The mark up I have is a bit complex. I basically need the animation on filter-column only. So when the page loads on mobile this column is hidden until you click a link which shows this column and hides everything else. What I want is for the column to slide in from the left and back again.

Answer (score 0):

try to modify your function like this:

```
function showOrHideFilter(show) {
    $("#results-container, .navbar-inverse" ).toggleClass( "hidden-xs", show );
    $("#filter-column").toggleClass("hidden-xs", !show); 
        if (show){
            $(this).animate({ width: 'hide' });
        }
}
```

Hope it was helpfull.